# Failed to load css when the css file is inside bin folder of web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web

I am working on a project that has many websites(asp.net mvc3.0). We need to maintain same UI for all websites. So i created a class library and put content and script folder in that library as embedded resource. It is working fine for java script files but fails to download css class.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) weburl/bin/Content/Site.css

Please suggest some solution.

Thanks,
Nabin

Comment: You don't want to serve files out of your bin folder. The bin folder should be hidden to users by default. The setting for this is in IIS -> Request Filtering -> Hidden Segments.

Comment: I totally agree that bin folder must be hidden to user or else it will create security problem. What is the best approach to use single copy of css file across multiple websites.

Comment: It's totally acceptable to point `<link href=` to central location for all sites, like a CDN. Like all sites could have `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.yoursite.net/content/all.css?v=62ff4813">`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to make it an embedded resource (and if you do you are accessing it incorrectly).

Click on the css file in your solutione explorer, then in the properties change the Build Action to content. Next change Copy to Output Directory to Copy if Newer.

This will accomplish what you want... although... I would not go about sharing css this way...

Comment: This problem is related with the way browser trying to download the css files. It works fine if the css files are in the content folder outside the bin. this error occurs only when the css files are inside bin folder. I guess this is something related with IIS security setting.

Comment: you cannot access it directly via with this method (unless you make bin public which is a bad idea)... in each site you will need to add a Css.aspx page and server the file from there. Let me know if you don't know how to do that...

Comment: But don't do it this way man, if you can just make a seperate shared server and put your shared css and other things there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.The idea of using shared server is fine but the risk is if that shared server is down all the websites will have problem which is not acceptable at any cost.

Comment: Then I guess you will have to create a Css.aspx page in each site and then load the file from the bin directory in the codebehind

Comment: @Nabin then you make sure your shared server has redundancy.